# abstract class in GORM polymorphism

Tags: hibernate, grails, inheritance, polymorphism, grails-orm

i'm working on a Grails project, Grails version : 2.2.0.
i have these classes :

```
public abstract class A {}
public class B extends A {}
public class C extends A {}
```

For now, everything is OK
class A is in : src/groovy so in DB i have two tables B & C.
now i add a new class :

```
public class D{
A aa
}
```

now that no longer works because hibernate don't cognize the Type A.
One solution is to omit the abstract term but  that allow instantiation of A object wich is not so right !
Does any one have an idea about how fix this probleme ? 
thank you

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368364/grails-2-abstract-domain-inheritance-issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this: GORM/Hibernate **must** be able to instantiate the domain class properties (except for the transient ones, of course). Because of this, a property cannot be of an abstract type. Interfaces don't work for the same reason.

To keep inheritance, unfortunately you'll have to do that *not so right* thing: drop the *abstract* and make `A` a domain class.

Comment: i didn't drop the abstract but i put the class A in the domain dir so that hibernate create a domain class .